# How to randomize the creation of objects of different classes? c++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, random, time

I'm doing project with classes in c++ which consists of a car that avoids obstacles on a board. I want to randomize the appearance of the object of classes EnemiesCar, Nail, Hole (the last two are subclasses of the first). The problem is that when i generate random number, it change too fast and the object that had appeared then disappears (the objects on the board come out intermittently between other object because the random number changes too fast). How can I fix this problem? Are there other solution for randomize objects of class? (I tried to do this function in Game::randomAppear(EnemiesCar &myEn, Nail &myNe, Hole &myHo), below I leave only the class EnemiesCar because its subclasses are similar).

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Nail.h"
#include "EnemiesCar.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include "Hole.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

Game::Game(){
    running = true;
    counter = 100;
    maxScore = 0;
    maxLevel = 1;
    timeS = 100.0;
    level = 1;
    levelUp = 1000;
    levelDown = 0;
}

void Game::gotoXY(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void Game::resetBoard()
{
    for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
        for(int i=1;i<20;i++){
            matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

void Game::createTab()
{
    for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<21;i++){
            if(i==0 || i==20){
                    gotoXY(i,j);
                    cout<<"b";
            }else if(j == 19){
                    gotoXY(i,j);
                    cout<<"*";
            }else if(matrix[i][j]==1){
                    gotoXY(i,j);
                    cout<<"m";
            }else if(matrix[i][j]==2){
                    gotoXY(i,j);
                    cout<<"e";
            }else if(matrix[i][j]==3){
                    gotoXY(i,j);
                    cout<<"c";
            }else if(matrix[i][j]==4){
                    gotoXY(i,j);
                    cout<<"h";
            }else {
                gotoXY(i,j);
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }
    }
}



void Game::checkSamePosition(EnemiesCar EN, Nail NE)
{
    if(NE.xPos == EN.xPos && NE.yPos == EN.yPos){
        NE.xPos = NE.xPos + 2;
    }
}

int Game::checkMaxScore()
{
    if(maxScore < counter){
        maxScore = counter;
    }
    return maxScore;
}

int Game::checkMaxLevel()
{
    if(maxLevel < level){
        maxLevel = level;
    }
    return maxLevel;
}

void Game::TabLevelUp()
{
    system("cls");
    gotoXY(5, 5);
    cout << "Next Level" << endl;
    gotoXY(5, 7);
    cout << "Level: " << level;
}

void Game::TabLevelDown()
{
    system("cls");
    gotoXY(5, 5);
    cout << "Previous Level" << endl;
    gotoXY(5, 7);
    cout << "Level: " << level;
}

void Game::gameLevels(Car &car)
{
    if(counter == levelUp){
        level++;
        TabLevelUp();
        Sleep(5000);
        gotoXY(40, 9);
        cout << "level " << level;
        levelDown = levelUp;
        levelUp = levelUp + 1000;
        gotoXY(40, 10);
        cout << "next " << levelUp;
        if(timeS >= 40){
            double update = timeS - 20.0;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(40, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }else if(timeS == 20 || timeS == 30){
            double update = timeS - 10.0;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(40, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }else if(timeS >= 10 && timeS < 20){
            double update = timeS - 5.0;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(40, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }else if(timeS == 0){
            Sleep(timeS);
        }else{
            double update = timeS - 0.5;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(40, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }
        playGame(car);
    }else if(counter < levelDown){
        level--;
        TabLevelDown();
        Sleep(5000);
        levelUp = levelDown;
        levelDown = levelDown - 1000;
        if(timeS >= 40 && timeS < 100){
            double update = timeS + 20.0;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(45, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }else if(timeS == 20 || timeS == 30){
            double update = timeS + 10.0;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(45, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }else if(timeS == 10 && timeS < 20){
            double update = timeS + 5.0;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(45, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }else if(timeS < 10 && level <= 17){
            double update = timeS + 0.5;
            timeS = update;
            gotoXY(45, 7);
            cout << "tmpIf " << timeS;
            Sleep(update);
        }else{
            Sleep(timeS);
        }
        playGame(car);
    }else{
        Sleep(timeS);
    }
}

void Game::showLevelScore()
{
    gotoXY(50, 1);
    cout<<"Score: " << counter;
    gotoXY(50, 3);
    cout<<"Level: " << level;
}

void Game::gameEnd()
{
    if(counter <= 0){
        running = false;
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");
        gotoXY(5,4);
        cout << "GAME OVER!!!";
        gotoXY(5,6);
        cout << "MAX LEVEL: " << checkMaxLevel();
        gotoXY(5,7);
        cout << "MAX SCORE: " << checkMaxScore();
        gotoXY(0,0);
    }
}
int Game::generateRandomNumber()
{
    int rEne = rand() % 3;
    gotoXY(50, 5);
    cout << "R: " << rEne << endl;
    return rEne;
}

void Game::randomAppear(EnemiesCar &myEn, Nail &myNe, Hole &myHo)
{
    int rEne = generateRandomNumber();
    if(rEne == 0){
        myEn.appear();
        myEn.drawEnemies(myEn.xPos, myEn.yPos, matrix);
        myEn.move();
    }else if(rEne == 1){
        myNe.appear();
        myNe.drawNails(myNe.xPos, myNe.yPos, matrix);
        myNe.move();
    }else{
        myHo.appear();
        myHo.drawHoles(myHo.xPos, myHo.yPos, matrix);
        myHo.move();
    }
}


void Game::playGame(Car &mycar){

    EnemiesCar myEnmCar = EnemiesCar();
    Nail nails = Nail();
    Hole holes = Hole();

    while(this->running){

        srand (time(NULL));
        resetBoard();

        randomAppear(myEnmCar, nails, holes);
        
        checkSamePosition(myEnmCar, nails);

        /*myEnmCar.appear();
        myEnmCar.drawEnemies(myEnmCar.xPos, myEnmCar.yPos, matrix);
        myEnmCar.move();*/
        /*gotoXY(3, 22);
        cout << "enmpos: " << myEnmCar.xPos << myEnmCar.yPos << endl;*/

        /*nails.appear();
        nails.drawNails(nails.xPos, nails.yPos, matrix);
        nails.move();

        holes.appear();
        holes.drawHoles(holes.xPos, holes.yPos, matrix);
        holes.move();*/

        mycar.drawCar(mycar.xPos, mycar.yPos, matrix);
        mycar.checkCollusion(myEnmCar, nails, holes, &counter, &level);

        createTab();

        myEnmCar.addScore(mycar, &counter);
        nails.addScore(mycar, &counter);
        holes.addScore(mycar, &counter);


        showLevelScore();

        checkMaxLevel();
        checkMaxScore();

        gameEnd();

        gameLevels(mycar);

    }
}

void Game::startGame()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    Car mycar = Car();


    thread myThread(&Car::myListener, &mycar, &mycar);


    playGame(mycar);


    Sleep(5000);


    myThread.detach();
}
```

**EnemiesCar.h**

```
#ifndef ENEMIESCAR_H
#define ENEMIESCAR_H
#include "Game.h"

class Game;
class Car;
class Nail;

class EnemiesCar
{
    public:
        const int xInit[9] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18};
        int xPos;
        int yPos;
        Game games = Game();

        EnemiesCar();
        void appear();
        void drawEnemies(int x, int y, int myMatr[21][20]);
        //void draw();
        void move();
        void addScore(Car car, int *countScore);
};

#endif // ENEMIESCAR_H
```

**EnemiesCar.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "EnemiesCar.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include "Nail.h"
using namespace std;

EnemiesCar::EnemiesCar()
{
        int randomX = rand() % 6;
        xPos=xInit[randomX];
        yPos=0;
}

/*void EnemiesCar::drawEnemies(int x, int y)
{
    Game games = Game();
    if(y<20 && y>=-0){
        games.matrix[x][y] = 2;
        cout << "drawEne" <<endl;
    }
}*/

void EnemiesCar::appear()
{
    if(yPos==18){
        int randomNo = rand() % 21;
        /*games.gotoXY(35, 7);
        cout << "a: " << randomNo << " ";*/
        if(randomNo >= 0 && randomNo <= 3){
            xPos = 2;
        }else if(randomNo == 4 || randomNo == 5){
            xPos = 4;
        }else if(randomNo == 6 || randomNo == 7){
            xPos = 6;
        }else if(randomNo == 8 || randomNo == 9){
            xPos = 8;
        }else if(randomNo == 10 || randomNo == 11){
            xPos = 10;
        }else if(randomNo == 12 || randomNo == 13){
            xPos = 12;
        }else if(randomNo == 14 || randomNo == 15){
            xPos = 14;
        }else if(randomNo == 16 || randomNo == 17){
            xPos = 16;
        }else{
            xPos = 18;
        }
        yPos = -3;
    }
}

void EnemiesCar::drawEnemies(int x, int y, int myMatr[21][20])
{
    if(y<20 && y>=-0){
        myMatr[x][y] = 2;
        myMatr[x-1][y+1] = 2;
        myMatr[x+1][y+1] = 2;
        myMatr[x][y+1] = 2;
        myMatr[x][y+2] = 2;
    }
}

void EnemiesCar::move()
{
    yPos++;
}

void EnemiesCar::addScore(Car car, int *countScore)
{
    if((this->xPos <= car.xPos-3 && this->yPos == 16) || (this->xPos >= car.xPos+3 && this->yPos == 16)){
        *countScore = *countScore + 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just get a random number in the range of `0` to `2` (very easy with [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)), and a `switch` for each of those cases.

Comment: Or if all have a common base-class (or is the base-class in itself) then an array of `X` elements, each being a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) which creates the appropriate object, and the return type is a pointer to the base-class. Then create a random number in the range of `0` to `X - 1` (inclusive) and use as an index to call the factory function.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "changes too fast"? Whenever you generate a random object, you get a (new) random object. Are you expecting to get the same one as before?

Comment: @einpoklum I'll give you an example, when rand() generate first number, for example 0, from my function an EnemiesCar appear, but the EnemiesCar does not have time to get to the bottom of the board because rand () generates another random number, for example 1 (so a Nail appears) and the EnemiesCar, that appeared previously, disappears (and then reappears if 0 comes out from rand () again). I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need to do is separate the appearance/drawing from the generation of the random number. You need to keep track of the "random enemies" you've already generated, and take them - and only them - into account when drawing your board; and independently of this, once every few turns or when triggered by appropriate events, generate a new random enemy/car/whatever, adding it to the set of already-generated ones.